# Need CSS advice for responsive web design on my project?

Tags: css

I'm coding the UI for my chat application and need some advice on the responsive web design part (on the tech side). Going straight into it, I have two views. A desktop view and a mobile view.

Desktop View:

[image: desktop view]

mobile view:

[image]

Basicly, I want the friendslist to disappear at mobile view. Any advice?

Comment: If you are familiar with Bootstrap then it's easy to handle (hide/show) some parts on web as well as on mobile [here](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possible solutions:

1. **Media Query**: It is a good way to go if you target device [support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries).
2. [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/): It is CSS and JS solution, an alternative to Media Query.
3. **Percentage measurements**: It is a CSS solutions for your layout components, you can add some tailored JS for showing or hiding parts.

Answer (score 0):

[Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Hide Friends List on all mobile devices

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 529px) {
  .friends-list-container{
    display: none; 
  }
}
```

Comment: And always note the browser compatibility of media queries.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you find the element that wraps the friends list and use Media queries to remove the element when breaking at a certain resolution using display:none;.

Dividing your page in identifiable segments will make this easier.